# Creating a dataframe where each cell is a vector in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
data.frame("color" = c( c("red", "red"), c("red"), c("red","green") ), rownames=letters[1:3] )
```

And I would like to make it into a dataframe with the following structure:

```
   color 
a  c("red", "red")
b  c("red")
c  c("red", "green")
```

where `a`,`b` and `c` are rownames.

The code I have above doesn't produce this, so how do I go about creating such a dataframe?

EDIT:
If I try to make the rownames as: paste("a",0:2,sep="",collapse=','), I get:

```
          color 
a0,a1,a2  c("red", "red")
a0,a1,a2  c("red")
a0,a1,a2  c("red", "green")
```

When what I want is:

```
   color 
a0  c("red", "red")
a1  c("red")
a2  c("red", "green")
```

How can I also rectify this?

Comment: Why not use a simple liste `list("a" = c("red", "red"), "b" = c("red"), "c" = c("red","green") )` ?

Comment: I may have more columns with rows that will be named the same, so I thought structuring it as a dataframe rather than several lists would be more efficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `I` function and put your vectors in a `list`:

```
data.frame("color" = I(list(c("red", "red"), 
                            c("red"), 
                            c("red","green"))), 
           row.names=letters[1:3] )
#        color
# a   red, red
# b        red
# c red, green
str(.Last.value)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ color:List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "red" "red"
#   ..$ : chr "red"
#   ..$ : chr  "red" "green"
#   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

---

Alternatively, with "data.table", you can create the list column directly (without `I`) but `data.table`s don't have row names, so you would need to add that as a column in your dataset.

```
library(data.table)
data.table("color" = list(c("red", "red"), "red", c("red", "green")), 
           "rownames" = letters[1:3])
#        color rownames
# 1:   red,red        a
# 2:       red        b
# 3: red,green        c
str(.Last.value)
# Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ color   :List of 3
#   ..$ : chr  "red" "red"
#   ..$ : chr "red"
#   ..$ : chr  "red" "green"
#  $ rownames: chr  "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes:

```
mydf <- data.frame(color = c( 'c("red", "red")', 'c("red")', 
'c("red","green")' ), row.names=letters[1:3] )

> mydf
         color
a  c("red", "red")
b         c("red")
c c("red","green")
```

Comment: I think they wanted the *structure* that is shown, not the character representation that they showed.

Comment: I was also doubting about that, but as OP  stated 'a dataframe' this is what I came up with.